# What is the proper method to make close button of NbAlertComponent to work (close an alert)

Tags: javascript, angular, nebular

I'm using [nebular](https://github.com/akveo/nebular) for my project, and cannot find out how to get `close button` of NbAlertComponent to actually close alert. By closing I mean to stop showing after clicking on `close button`. I read documentation about alert component [docs](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/alert/overview#nbalertcomponent), but did not found an answer. Alert component can have property `closable`, which adds close button, and can have event handler when clicked on it `(close)="onClose()"`. I'm using it this way (angular 6):

```
// page.component.html
<nb-alert status="success" closable (close)="onClose()">
  You have been successfully authenticated!
</nb-alert>
```

In page.component.ts, if I have a method `onClose`, it fires every time I click on alert `close button`, but how to actually close it?

```
// page.component.ts
onClose() {

  // fires after each click on close button:
  console.log('close button was clicked');
}
```

Here is some code from alert component related close functionality:

```
// alert.component.ts
/**
  * Emits when chip is removed
  * @type EventEmitter<any>
  */
  // this is an instance of NbAlertComponent
  this.close = new EventEmitter();

/**
 * Emits the removed chip event
 */
NbAlertComponent.prototype.onClose = function () {
    this.close.emit();
};
```

Comment: use can simply create a css class that has display none property

Comment: @ThanveerShah, thanks, it's one of the way, which I end up to use

Answer (score 3):

In this case you should be able to use the `*ngIf` directive provided by Angular itself like so.

```
// page.component.html
<nb-alert status="success" closable (close)="onClose()" *ngIf="alertIsOpen">
  You have been successfully authenticated!
</nb-alert>
```

```
alertIsOpen = true;

// page.component.ts
onClose() {
  // fires after each click on close button:
  console.log('close button was clicked');
  this.alertIsOpen = false;
}
```

---

Another approach which would also work for multiple alerts would be to have your alerts exist in an array.

```
// page.component.html
<ng-container *ngFor="alert of alerts">
 <nb-alert status="{{alert.status}}" closable (close)="onClose(alert)">
   {{alert.text}}
 </nb-alert>
</ng-container>
```

```
alerts = [
 {
   status: "success",
   text: "You have been successfully authenticated!"
 },
 {
   status: "danger",
   text: "Failed to authenticate!"
 }
]

// page.component.ts
onClose(alert) {
  // fires after each click on close button:
  console.log('close button was clicked');
  this.alerts.splice(this.alerts.indexOf(alert), 1);
}
```

---

The benefit of these approaches are that you don't keep the alert existing inside your DOM

Comment: What if I have several alerts?

Comment: @Vadi I updated the answer with a solution that would allow for more alerts without having to separately define `isClosed` variables for them